# Use of fractions with nouns of measurement

Tags: meaning, grammatical-case, declension

Here is a sentence

> Er verfehlte den Rekord um ein Viertel einer Sekunde.

Firstly, is "einer Sekunde" used in the Genitive or Dative case in this context and why? Secondly, I read that one may omit the determiner "einer" from "Sekunde" if the determiner "ein" is used before the denominator of the fraction. Is that so?

Answer (score 8):

This is a genitive: "a quarter **of** a second". A genitive translates to "of".

You cannot omit any one word in that sentence and have it still be grammatical. What you might mean is that you can instead say "eine Viertelsekunde" (a quarter-second). This is a different word, it is a compound of "Viertel" and "Sekunde".